# cat lines into file after regex

Tags: regex, cat

I want to add the info below into the file usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg but want to do it just below ##company in the hosts.cfg file. My setup script will contain the info that needs to be added

I have spend hours trying to get sed to just add a line into a file after a marker  but to no avail

```
define host{
use                         linux-box
host_name                   $host_name
alias                       $alias
address                     $ip 
parents                     $parent
notification_period         24x7
notification_interval       5
}
```

Previously I used 
    cat <> /path /filename 
    EOT
but now I need to do it in specif places in the file

Comment: Use `sed` (probably with `-f script.sed` to specify the script since it will need multiple lines) to find the insertion point and add the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following `file`:

```
# some content

###company
```

If I run the following command:

```
sed -i 's/###company/&\ndefine host {\nuse host\nhost_name HOSTNAME/' file
```

Now, the contents of `file` are:

```
# some content

###company
define host {
use host
host_name HOSTNAME
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you it added the lines as I needed them